# After updating from Symfony 5.3 to 6, I got a Kernel error

Tags: php, symfony

After updating my composer, I got the following error when upgrading to Symfony 6:

> Typed property Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::$env must not be accessed before initialization

It showed the trace on my `Kernel.php` file on line 30:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
    {
        $container->import('../config/{packages}/*.yaml');
        $container->import('../config/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');

        if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.yaml')) {
            $container->import('../config/services.yaml');
            $container->import('../config/{services}_'.$this->environment.'.yaml');
        } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.php')) {
            (require $path)($container->withPath($path), $this);
        }
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RoutingConfigurator $routes): void
    {
        $routes->import('../config/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');
        $routes->import('../config/{routes}/*.yaml'); //<--- Error pointing here 

        if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/routes.yaml')) {
            $routes->import('../config/routes.yaml');
        } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/routes.php')) {
            (require $path)($routes->withPath($path), $this);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect this actually has nothing to do with my Kernel file, but my `routing.yaml` file?

`routing.yaml` contents:

```yaml
framework:
    router:
        utf8: true
            # Configure how to generate URLs in non-HTTP contexts, such as CLI commands.
            # See https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-commands
            #default_uri: http://localhost
```

---

I updated all of my packages utilizing `composer recipes:update`. After running that command, I'm now back to the original error:

> Typed property Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::$env must not be accessed before initialization

I compared the file with the original here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Annotation/Route.php and it's exactly the same.

After running `bin/console cache:clear` I got the following message:

```
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\FrameworkExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\FrameworkExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\DependencyInjection\SensioFrameworkExtraExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\DependencyInjection\SensioFrameworkExtraExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\DependencyInjection\TwigExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\DependencyInjection\TwigExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\DependencyInjection\WebProfilerExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\DependencyInjection\WebProfilerExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\MonologExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\MonologExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DependencyInjection\DebugExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DependencyInjection\DebugExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\DependencyInjection\MakerExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\DependencyInjection\MakerExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineMigrationsExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineMigrationsExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\DependencyInjection\TwigExtraExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\DependencyInjection\TwigExtraExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\DependencyInjection\WebpackEncoreExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\DependencyInjection\WebpackEncoreExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\DependencyInjection\SymfonyCastsVerifyEmailExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\DependencyInjection\SymfonyCastsVerifyEmailExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineFixturesExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineFixturesExtension"]
00:00:27 WARNING   [app] Failed to generate ConfigBuilder for extension SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\DependencyInjection\SymfonyCastsResetPasswordExtension. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException^ { …},"extensionClass" => "SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\DependencyInjection\SymfonyCastsResetPasswordExtension"]
00:00:27 CRITICAL  [php] Uncaught Error: Typed property Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::$env must not be accessed before initialization ["exception" => Error { …}]
```

The only place I see that has the `$env` variable is within `bin/.phpunit/phpunit-8.5-0/**` in 4 files within that directory.

Comment: In one of your controllers, do you have a property `$env`? Basically what the error is saying is that the property ($env) hasn't been initialised, it isn't even *null*, it is *undefined*...

Comment: I don't. I just checked all of my controllers. No variable by that name

Comment: Something may have gone wrong while upgrading.. Just comparing [5.3 Routes.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.3/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Annotation/Route.php) with [6.0 Routes.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Annotation/Route.php) there is a change to the $env property. What does your Routes.php file look like? 5.3 or 6.0? Found in `vendor/symfony/routing/annotation`

Comment: It looks like 6.0

Comment: I suspect this is related to your earlier question on trying to manually update from 5.3 to 6.0 with a somewhat messed up composer.json file.  Quite few of the recipes have changed in Symfony so upgrading is a bit problematical.  The default kernel file is, for example, basically empty now.  And I think I have seen this error before when Symfony introduced it's runtime component.  Once again you might want to start with a fresh 6.0 app and see the differences.  There are also some recipe update commands you can try.

Comment: To be honest i'm unsure with the information at hand, try `php bin/console cache:clear` if not hopefully someone will be able to help...

Comment: As already said, the recipes (configuration and other files copied on installation) have probably changed since your first installation. I'd recommend updating flex first to 1.18.0 or 2.1.0 to be able to use the [new interactive recipe updater](https://symfony.com/blog/fast-smart-flex-recipe-upgrades-with-recipes-update), as in your previous question you were using 1.3. With older versions, you can still check what needs to be updated with `composer recipes` or replace them with new versions with `composer recipes:install`.

Comment: Interesting, when I tried to update a recipe, I got this: "Error applying the patch: error: .env: does not exist in index" - however, my .env file does exist within the index of the file structure like so: >project folder -> .env

Comment: I believe that index refers to the git index, not the folder itself. Is your project (and specifically, that file) under version control? From the linked announcement: "This command is smart: it generates a "diff" between the originally-installed version of recipe and the latest version, *then leverages git to apply that patch*".

Comment: Back to the original error, but I reduced what's in kernal.php exactly like it is in my new project and the error has returned.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: That kind of message appears when typed properties are not initialized, but [it should](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/554980c78d5f74892b0d33e3e76cc2fd4b8f26be/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Annotation/Route.php#L52), using constructor promotion available in PHP8. You *shouldn't* have been able to upgrade with lower versions, but just to confirm: what version are you running?

Comment: It says: "The Web server is using PHP FPM 8.0.7 "

Comment: @Bossman when I tried `php bin/console cache:clear` it's giving me an error: `Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate   
  24564976 bytes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.

After creating a separate new Symfony 6 project, this was the cause of the error:

`framework.yaml`

```
session:
        # enabled: true
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
```

to

```
session:
        # enabled: true
        handler_id: null
```

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone, I had a similar issue after upgrading from symfony 5 to 6.

```
Typed property Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::$name must not be accessed before initialization
```

Clearing the cache resolved this issue for me:

```sh
php bin/console cache:clear
# or if running php unit tests fails
php bin/console cache:clear --env=test
```